# Pods with status container creating and with container started

Tags: php, kubernetes, deployment, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster running version 1.28, where I'm experiencing issues related to php-fpm pods.

My pods remain in the "container creating" status even after the containers have started successfully and are generating logs.

```
Name:             api-test-php-5965d59686-ldd7s
Namespace:        api-test-producao
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             ip-172-81-11-245.sa-east-1.compute.internal/172.81.11.245
Start Time:       Mon, 09 Oct 2023 17:37:06 -0300
Labels:           app=api-test-php
                  pod-template-hash=5965d59686
Annotations:      co.elastic.logs/enabled: true
Status:           Pending
IP:               
IPs:              <none>
Controlled By:    ReplicaSet/api-test-php-5965d59686
Containers:
  api-test-php:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          ***********.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/api-test:php-90
    Image ID:       
    Port:           9000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     800m
      memory:  256Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  128Mi
    Environment Variables from:
      api-test-php  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:     <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-kl7xj (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-kl7xj:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------

  Normal   Scheduled         44s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned api-test-producao/api-test-php-5965d59686-ldd7s to ip-172-81-11-245.sa-east-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulling           43s                  kubelet            Pulling image "814635504079.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/api-test:php-90"
  Normal   Pulled            35s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "814635504079.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/api-test:php-90" in 7.74s (7.74s including waiting)
  Normal   Created           35s                  kubelet            Created container api-test-php
  Normal   Started           35s                  kubelet            Started container api-test-php
```

Has anyone experienced this before or can help identify the error?

I've tried many approaches... the only one that worked was changing the repository from which the image is pulled, using a clean image from Docker Hub.

Comment: In the pod description, Both the `Image Id` and `container Id` are empty. Could you please share your deployment config?

Comment: Also share the replica set events.

Comment: `Status:           Pending`
`IP:               `
`IPs:              <none>`
looks like the pod is not scheduled on any node?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

In my deployment, I was creating the Laravel log file. These commands worked well on eks 1.21. On eks 1.28, I had to add "sudo" to the "tail" command for some reason.

Below is my corrected and now functional deployment. Thanks for the help.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: $K8S_DEPLOY_NAME_PHP
  namespace: $K8S_NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app: $K8S_APP_NAME_PHP
    role: $K8S_APP_ROLE
  annotations:
    co.elastic.logs/enabled: $ELASTIC_ANNOTATIONS_HINTS
spec:
  #replicas: $K8S_APP_SCALE_MIN
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 0
  replicas: $K8S_APP_SCALE_MIN_PHP
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: $K8S_APP_NAME_PHP
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: $K8S_APP_NAME_PHP
      annotations:
        co.elastic.logs/enabled: $ELASTIC_ANNOTATIONS_HINTS
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: $K8S_DEPLOY_NAME_PHP
          image: $K8S_DEPLOY_IMAGE_NAME_PHP:$K8S_DEPLOY_IMAGE_TAG_PHP
          lifecycle:
              postStart:
                exec:
                  command:
                      - /bin/bash
                      - -c
                      - >
                          touch /var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log &&
                          chgrp -R www-data /var/www/bootstrap/ /var/www/storage/ /var/www/storage/logs/ &&
                          chmod -R g+w /var/www/bootstrap/ /var/www/storage/ /var/www/storage/logs/ &&
                          sudo tail -f /var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log > /proc/1/fd/2 &
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: $K8S_REQUESTS_CPU_PHP
              memory: $K8S_REQUESTS_MEMORY_PHP
            limits:
              cpu: $K8S_LIMITS_CPU_PHP
              memory: $K8S_LIMITS_MEMORY_PHP
          ports:
          - containerPort: $K8S_DEPLOY_IMAGE_PORT_PHP
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: $K8S_DEPLOY_NAME_PHP
```